# How to make a Vaadin Grid Columns sortable with data from CrudEntityDataProvider?

Tags: dataprovider, vaadin-grid, vaadin-flow, vaadin10

How to make a Vaadin Grid's Columns sortable with data from a ***CrudEntityDataProvider*** ?

the best example for this case is Bakery App -> Users grid https://bakery-flow.demo.vaadin.com/users

I try with a **ListDataProvider**

```
ListDataProvider trainingsArtProvider = DataProvider.ofItems(TrainingsArt.getAllTrainingsArten());
```

and the columns are sortable, but the filters are ignored and any edit ending with a RuntimeException

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown
>   key: 97

The goal is to have a sortable AND filterable grid in a simple way.

It is even possible to achieve this?

Comment: Have you read the docs: https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/binding-data/tutorial-flow-data-provider.html

Comment: Are you still lookin for a solution?

Comment: Thank you for asking!, This was for me a "either ... or" (sortable or filterable) problem, so I decide to use as it is and see in the futures for a solutions.. :)